# Grails formRemote update browser url

Tags: html, url, grails

I am building a single page grails application which uses `formRemote` and `submitToRemote` tag to load new `.gsp` pages into a div in my current page.

On each of these updates, I want to change the browser url and allow back button on the browser window to get back to previous state of my `.gsp` (the state before page is updated).

Is it possible to change the browser url on div update in my grails application?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you have tried or thinking of trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html5 provides a history api which will allow you to achieve your single page application browsers back button issue try this link 'http://html5demos.com/history'.
I will suggest you to check some single page application framework like 'angularjs' which might help you a lot with your application